# How to make sure vendor bundle is always cached unless updated?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

In my current build process, i have 2 bundles:

1. `main.[some_hash].js` (source code)
2. `vendor.[some_hash].js` (dependencies)

Since they both have a hash, with every build the hash changes, so in the case of the vendor bundle - even if no dependncy has changed, it would invalidate the browser cache.

On the other hand, if i omit the hash and just name the bundle `vendor.js` - how can i invalidate the browser cache on the client side when i add/remove a dependency?

Is there a common/recommended pattern for this?

Answer (score 1):

Give **HardSourceWebpackPlugin** a try:

https://github.com/mzgoddard/hard-source-webpack-plugin

This ought to ensure that entry outputs (regardless of hashing) does not get rebuilt until there are actual changes to be built.

Great for continues integrations / CLI